# UI table view dequeue reusable cell in wrong order when refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This bug appears when we do refreshing on the table. Well, to refresh, we need to swipe down on the table view and it does a simple job, calls `tableView(didEndDisplaying cell:)` to hide all cells, then `tableView(cellForRowAt indexPath:)` to update the cell data, and `tableView(willDisplay cell:)` to deqeue the ready-to-go cell back to the table view. But when we swipe down, the last cell of the table goes off the screen and the UITableViewController calls the `tableView(didEndDisplaying cell:)` after the above function calling sequence ends and cause the order of the cell queue a mess.

So the sequence occurs under the hood of a refresh action is:

1. My table view only shows 3 cells at a time.
2. User swipe down on table view, cause the last cell go off the screen, refresh control activated,
3. `tableview.reloadData()`called by refresh control selector, it will update all the cells, no matter which are shown on the table or not.
4. `tableView(didEndDisplay cell:)` called in the backend to hide the appeared cells.
5. `tableView(cellForRowAt indexPath:)` executed, it updates all cell's data.
6. `tableView(willDisplay cell:)` brings the updated cells which can be fit in the screen back to the table. In my case, only the top 3 cells.
7. At this point, refresh control finished. However `viewWillDisplay()`
   is not called yet and my screen shows only 2 cells due to **step 2's swipe down**. So the UIView will calculate the cells dimension to decide which cell to display.
8. *Things turn horrible at this point.*
9. `tableView(didEndDisplay cell:)` is called Again! on the 3rd cell, since **2's swipe down** did hide the 3rd cell.
10. After 9. the order of the reusable cell queue is wrong and cause the cell data afterwards all in a mess.

It takes me a while to figure out the bug. But Is my analysis correct on the tableView's behavior? Refresh on table view contradicts table cells appearance. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial to implement refresh control to refresh data in the table view:
https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/pull-to-refresh-how-to-implement-f915743703f8

Comment: In my opinion, the tutorial is kinda old since iOS 10 comes with refreshControl built-in in UITableViewController.

Comment: From this tutorial, you can follow the same steps. Since refreshControl is by default nil. You need to assign a refresh control to this property to implement its behaviour. [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/1614752-refreshcontrol]

Comment: yes, I just declaire a lazy var for refreshControl and the bug still appears.